# My regexp in php is not working correctly, but does work at RegexPal.com

Tags: php, regex

When running the code below in a php file named: "ugh.php", I get the following output:

```
NO, match: a      <- This is correct
YES, match: 123   <- This is correct
YES, match: 1,23  <- This is NOT correct
YES, match: 1.23  <- This is NOT correct
YES, match: 1,234 <-This is correct
YES, match: 1234  <-This is correct
```

The goal of my rexexp is to allow for a currency to be entered in an html form field (whole dollars only, commas are optional).  I have indicated above what is working and what is not.

However, when I enter my regexp at the following website: http://www.regexpal.com/
1,23 and 1.23 both indicate NO match, which is the correct response.

```
<?php
$curency = array("a", "123", "1,23", "1.23", "1,234", "1234");

foreach ($curency as $item)
{
    if ( preg_match("/\b\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*\b/", $item) )
    {
        echo 'YES, match: ' . $item . '<br>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'NO, match: ' . $item . '<br>';
    }   
}
?>
```

**Why do these not indicate "NO, match" when I test them in my php file?**

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Here's a useful troubleshooting tool: http://regexper.com/#%2F%5Cb%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D(%3F%3A%2C%3F%5Cd%7B3%7D)*%5Cb%2F .  When I ran them through regexpal I did see those as matches as well, the same as your php code. Copy that full URL as it did not link properly...

Comment: it's due to partial match... You have to force complete match using anchors (check Josh's answer bellow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using word boundaries, use the [start/end of string `^`/`$` anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

```
preg_match("/^\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*$/", $item)
```

The problem with `/\b\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*\b/`, is that the strings `"1,23"`/`"1.23"` would partially match and return true. By using the anchors `^`/`$`, you are checking from the start to the end of the string to see if the entire string matches.

Comment: Josh,  Thanks your quick and accurate response.  First time that I have posted to Stack Overflow.  I have used it many times reading other questions that have been posted by others.  Mike